# Vectorising a function over pandas - unknown window length/index range

Tags: python, pandas, function, vectorization

I have a dataframe as below.

```
          signal   positions.  rates
Date            
2018-01-02  0      NaN         1.2065
2018-01-03  0      0.0         1.2023
2018-01-04  0      0.0         1.2065
2018-01-05  1      1.0         1.2045
2018-01-08  0.    -1.0         1.1973
2018-01-09  0      0.0         1.1932
2018-01-10  0      0.0         1.1992
2018-01-11  1      1.0         1.2017
2018-01-12  1      0.0         1.2137
2018-01-15  0     -1.0         1.22
```

Based on the position column, i wish to create a new columns called entryRate.
All rows between a position of 1 and -1 are to have the same rate : the rate when position = 1. For ex:

```
          signal    positions   rates   entryRate
Date                
2018-01-02  0       NaN         1.2065  0.0000
2018-01-03  0       0.0         1.2023  0.0000
2018-01-04  0       0.0         1.2065  0.0000
2018-01-05  1       1.0         1.2045  1.2045
2018-01-08  0      -1.0         1.1973  1.2045
2018-01-09  0       0.0         1.1932  0.0000
2018-01-10  0       0.0         1.1992  0.0000
2018-01-11  1       1.0         1.2017  1.2017
2018-01-12  1       0.0         1.2137  1.2017
2018-01-15  0      -1.0         1.2277  1.2017
```

Currently am looping over the rows to implement this. The condition is formed on the signal column that stays = 1 between position =1 and position=-1

```
dat['entryRate'] = 0
        i=0
        while(i<len(dat)):
            if (dat.iloc[i,0]==1):
                entry = dat.iloc[i,2]
                while (dat.iloc[i,0]==1):
                    dat.iloc[i,3]=entry
                    i+=1

                    #end of dataframe cond
                    if(i==len(dat)):
                        break

                #update one more row after end of while loop, don't update if end of dataframe is reached
                if i<len(dat):
                    dat.iloc[i,4]=entry

            else:
                i+=1
```

Any nice way to vectorize this function? I can't put a finger on what to use - apply, merge asof, etc.

Appreciate any and all suggestions guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a better vectorised solution, but I think this one is better than what you have

```
entryRate = 0.0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['positions'] == 1.0:
        entryRate = row['rates']
        df.loc[i,'entryRate'] = entryRate
    elif row['positions'] == -1.0:
        df.loc[i,'entryRate'] = entryRate
        entryRate = 0.0
    else:
        df.loc[i,'entryRate'] = entryRate
```

Result:

```
            signal  positions   rates  entryRate
Date                                            
2018-01-02       0        NaN  1.2065     0.0000
2018-01-03       0        0.0  1.2023     0.0000
2018-01-04       0        0.0  1.2065     0.0000
2018-01-05       1        1.0  1.2045     1.2045
2018-01-08       0       -1.0  1.1973     1.2045
2018-01-09       0        0.0  1.1932     0.0000
2018-01-10       0        0.0  1.1992     0.0000
2018-01-11       1        1.0  1.2017     1.2017
2018-01-12       1        0.0  1.2137     1.2017
2018-01-15       0       -1.0  1.2200     1.2017
```

Comment: Thanks David! Still searching for the 'better' solution, but this is certainly better than what i had